# Upsert with a transaction

Tags: sql, database, spring, postgresql

I'm using Spring with PostgreSQL and I try to do a sort of UPSERT by using a code like this:

```
jt.update("delete from A where id = 1")
jt.update("insert into A (id, value) values (1, 100)")
```

wrapped inside a transaction (using `@Transactional`).

The problem is that, when there are many concurrent requests, this code fails with 'duplicate key' errors, meaning the transaction is not isolated, or...

Am I missing something about how transactions work? Should I use a different mechanism here (ex. thread synchronization)?

Comment: As always: Postgres version? Table definition? I assume `id` is unique, but `value` is not?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I wrote a rather large blogpost about it, so even though I might get downvotes for links, read [this](http://www.depesz.com/2012/06/10/why-is-upsert-so-complicated/).

The gist is that transactions do not help in here (at least by default), and while it is possible to write correct upsert, it's actually pretty tricky.

Comment: Huh, I already sprinkle links to that post around rather liberally. It's a very useful resource, thanks.

Comment: @CraigRinger: I once (couple of months ago) provided answer by linking to my blogpost, which was apparently "not ok". Don't remember details now, so can't provide link.

Comment: @CraigRinger: Actually, depesz is right about `barely more than a link to an external site`. It's in the [list of criteria why answers may be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers). Now, *we* know that depesz is an expert in the field, and that the link is good. The rules apply for everybody, though.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Good point; I tend to elaborate considerably on the answer, not *just* link, and I do think that policy is valuable. Not least because external links move/vanish. What I tend to do in this case is have one full-size answer with some links to external articles for supporting detail, then link to that answer with a very short explanation when similar issues come up later. I find that works well.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming this simple table:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl(id int primary key, value int);
```

This function *almost* 100% secure (see comments) for concurrent transactions.:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_upsert(_id int, _value int)
  RETURNS void AS
$func$
BEGIN
LOOP
   UPDATE tbl SET value = _value WHERE  id = _id;

   EXIT WHEN FOUND;

   BEGIN
      INSERT INTO tbl (id, value)
      VALUES (_id, _value);

      RETURN;

   EXCEPTION WHEN UNIQUE_VIOLATION THEN     -- tbl.id has UNIQUE constraint.
      RAISE NOTICE 'It actually happened!'; -- hardly ever happens
   END;

END LOOP;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Call:

```
SELECT f_upsert(2, 2);
```

It's very similar to this `INSERT / SELECT` case with more explanation and links:

- [Is SELECT or INSERT in a function prone to race conditions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15939902/is-my-function-prone-to-race-conditions/15950324#15950324)

Comment: I'm not convinced it's "100% safe", but it doesn't suffer from the usual obvious faults like lost updates, racing on an `EXISTS` test, etc. `UPDATE` will block on an uncommitted `INSERT`s then the re-check will cause it to return zero rows, so you handle the rollback-after-insert problem. I think it's safe if the function is the *only* thing you do in the transaction. You can still lose updates if you try to do more than one upsert per transaction. It'll also only work correctly in `READ COMMITTED` mode.

Comment: It's the same approach as from http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING btw

Comment: @CraigRinger: Very good link. The [`UPSERT` example](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-UPSERT-EXAMPLE) uses almost an identical code path, so the notes fit perfectly.