# Insert if not exists else update it in Netezza

Tags: sql, postgresql, upsert, netezza

I am having issue using if not exists statement in Netezza.  I am trying to check if record is not there first then insert else update the record.  I could not find a better way to do this in Netezza. Here is what I have but does not work:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT ID FROM OLD_TABLE WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM NEW TABLE ) )
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE (NAME, LOCATION)
ELSE 
UPDATE NEW_TABLE
SET NAME = X.NAME
FROM (SELECT NAME, LOCATION FROM OLD_TABLE)AS X
WHERE X.NAME = NEW_TABLE.NAME
```

Comment: First you check for `ID`, then you connect via `NAME`. And you only want to update `NAME`, not `LOCATION`? Please clarify. Also, do you want to upsert all rows from old_table or just a particular one? Which one?

Comment: i want to update both Name and Location.  I only want to insert into the New_Table the ID's that are present in Old_Table but not in the New_Table.  I hope that clarifies.  thanks

Comment: Yes, I think I see what you are after. Please clarify the question accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are providing an ID and want to UPSERT a single row in `new_table` with values from `old_table`. I am using a [data-modifying CTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING), which requires Postgres 9.1 or later:

```
WITH input AS (SELECT 123 AS id)
, upd AS (
   UPDATE new_table n
   SET    name = o.name
        , location = o.location
   FROM   old_table o, input i
   WHERE  n.id = o.id
   AND    n.id = i.id
   RETURNING id
   )
INSERT INTO new_table (id, name, location)
SELECT o.id, o.name, o.location
FROM   old_table o, input i 
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM upd)
AND    o.id = i.id;
```

Here is a closely related answer with more explanation:
[Problems with a PostgreSQL upsert query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20390037/problems-with-a-postgresql-upsert-query/20390673#20390673)

There is a tiny chance for a race condition. If you are planning to use this under heavy concurrent load, consider this related question and the links for more:
[Upsert with a transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17152860/upsert-with-a-transaction)

#### Whole table

To upsert the whole table:

```
WITH upd AS (
   UPDATE new_table n
   SET    name = o.name
        , location = o.location
   FROM   old_table o
   WHERE  n.id = o.id
   RETURNING id
   )
INSERT INTO new_table (id, name, location)
SELECT o.id, o.name, o.location
FROM   old_table o
LEFT   JOIN upd u USING (id)
WHERE  u.id IS NULL;
```