# Insert (if not present) and return id

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have a unique column. I want to insert a row if it's not already there, and then return the `id` of that row.

```
INSERT INTO t(a) VALUES ('a') ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING RETURNING t.id;
```

returns nothing at all. [Here's a fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/a7201/6).
I'm looking for how to get 1 each time, whether 'a' was newly inserted or not.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39779145/330315

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24050779/330315

Answer (score 4):

```
with i as (
    INSERT INTO t(a) VALUES ('a') ON CONFLICT (a) DO NOTHING RETURNING id
)
select id from i
union all
select id from t where a = 'a'
limit 1
```