# Postgresql: Insert from huge csv file, collect the ids and respect unique constraints

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-queryset, django-postgresql

In a postgresql database:

```
class Persons(models.Model):
    person_name = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)
```

The `persons.csv` file, contains 1 million names.

```
$cat persons.csv
Name-1
Name-2
...
Name-1000000
```

I want to:

1. Create the names that do not already exist
2. Query the database and fetch the id for each name contained in the csv file.

My approach:

1. Use the [`COPY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/sql-copy.html) command or the [django-postgres-copy](https://github.com/california-civic-data-coalition/django-postgres-copy) application that implements it.

   Also take advantage of the new Postgresql-9.5+ [upsert feature](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/What%27s_new_in_PostgreSQL_9.5#INSERT_..._ON_CONFLICT_DO_NOTHING.2FUPDATE_.28.22UPSERT.22.29).
2. Now, all the names in the csv file, are also in the database.

   I need to get their ids -from the database- either in memory or in another csv file with an efficient way:

   - Use [`Q`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Q) objects

     ```
     list_of_million_q = <iterate csv and append Qs>
     million_names = Names.objects.filter(list_of_million_q)
     ```

     **or**
   - Use [`__in`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in) to filter based on a list of names:

     ```
     list_of_million_names = <iterate csv and append strings>
     million_names = Names.objects.filter(
         person_name__in=[list_of_million_names]
     )
     ```

     **or**

     ?

I do not feel that any of the above approaches for fetching the ids is efficient.

### **Update**

There is a third option, along the lines of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42217872/2996101) that should be a great solution which combines all the above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34708509/how-to-use-returning-with-on-conflict-in-postgresql/42217872#42217872) describes how to use `RETURNING` with `ON CONFLICT` so while inserting into the database the contents of the csv file, the ids will be saved in another table either when an insertion was successful, or when -due to unique constraints- the insertion was omitted.

I have tested it in [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com) where I used [a set up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48019381/how-postgresql-copy-to-stdin-with-csv-do-on-conflic-do-update/49836011#49836011) that resembles the one used for the [`COPY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/sql-copy.html) command which inserts to the database straight from a csv file, respecting the unique constraints.

The schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS label (
  id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  label_name varchar(200) NOT NULL UNIQUE
  );
INSERT INTO label (label_name) VALUES
  ('Name-1'),
  ('Name-2');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ids (
  id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  label_ids varchar(12) NOT NULL
  );
```

The script:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp_table
(LIKE label INCLUDING DEFAULTS)
ON COMMIT DROP;

INSERT INTO tmp_table (label_name) VALUES
  ('Name-2'),
  ('Name-3');

WITH ins AS(
  INSERT INTO label 
  SELECT *
  FROM tmp_table
  ON CONFLICT (label_name) DO NOTHING
  RETURNING id
)
INSERT INTO ids (label_ids)
SELECT
  id FROM ins
UNION ALL
SELECT
  l.id FROM tmp_table
JOIN label l USING(label_name);
```

The output:

```
SELECT * FROM ids;
SELECT * FROM label;
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM persons;
```

make a name: id dictionary out of the names recieved from the database:

```
db_dict = {'Harry': 1, 'Bob': 2, ...}
```

Query the dictionary:

```
ids = []
for name in list_of_million_names:
    if name in db_dict:
        ids.append(db_dict[name])
```

This way you're using the quick dictionary indexing as opposed to the slower `if x in list` approach.

But the only way to really know for sure is to benchmark these 3 approaches.

Comment: If the table `Persons` has millions of entries, `SELECT * FROM persons;` will bloat the memory, won't it?

Comment: Even 10 million entries with names of 10 characters long will only take in about half a gig in memory, so that's not really a bottleneck.

Comment: I understand your point but I am running on a budget server with 1Gb memory for all operations! Probably something in the lines of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46953777/2996101) could do the job.

Comment: Is this something that you need to do often? Because if so, you should probably save the output somewhere.

Comment: Yes this will be done oftenly. It would be ideal to `insert` or `do nothing`and save the returning ids to a csv file.