# First_or_create yet ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord, race-condition, select-insert

I have the following code:

```
rating = user.recipe_ratings.where(:recipe_id => recipe.id).where(:delivery_id => delivery.id).first_or_create
```

Yet somehow we get occasional `PG::Error: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint` errors from this. I can't think of any reason that should happen, since the whole point of `first_or_create` is to prevent those.

Is this just a crazy race-condition? How can I solve this without a maddening series of `begin...rescue` blocks?

Comment: Don't use `first_or_create` at all, do it by hand. Even your own version that did the naive SELECT/INSERT inside an exception handling wrapper would be better than AR's `first_or_create`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to stem from a typical **race condition** for the "SELECT or INSERT" case.

Ruby seems to choose *performance* over *safety* in its implementation. Quoting ["Ruby on Rails Guides"](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/active_record_querying.html#first_or_create):

> The `first_or_create` method checks whether first returns `nil` or not. If
> it does return `nil`, then `create` is called.
>
> ...
>
> The SQL generated by this method looks like this:
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM clients WHERE (clients.first_name = 'Andy') LIMIT 1
> BEGIN
> INSERT INTO clients (created_at, first_name, locked, orders_count, updated_at)
> VALUES ('2011-08-30 05:22:57', 'Andy', 0, NULL, '2011-08-30 05:22:57')
> COMMIT
> ```

If that's the actual implementation (?), it seems *completely* open for race conditions. Another transaction can easily `SELECT` between the first transaction's `SELECT` and `INSERT`. And then try its own `INSERT`, which would raise the error you reported, since the first transaction has inserted the row in the meantime.

The time frame for a race condition could be drastically reduced with a data-modifying CTE. Even a safe version would not cost that much more. But I guess they have their reasons.
Compare this safe implementation:

- [Is SELECT or INSERT in a function prone to race conditions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15939902/is-select-or-insert-in-a-function-prone-to-race-conditions/15950324#15950324)

Comment: Is there a way to fix this then?

Comment: @hobberwickey: Follow the link.

Answer (score 2):

Rails 6 adds a new [create_or_find_by](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-create_or_find_by) method that alleviates a possible **race condition**, with a few drawbacks:

> - The underlying table must have the relevant columns defined with unique constraints.
> - A unique constraint violation may be triggered by only one, or at least less than all, of the given attributes. This means that the subsequent `find_by!` may fail to find a matching record, which will then raise an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` exception, rather than a record with the given attributes.
> - While we avoid the race condition between SELECT -> INSERT from `find_or_create_by`, we actually have another race condition between INSERT -> SELECT, which can be triggered if a DELETE between those two statements is run by another client. But for most applications, that's a significantly less likely condition to hit.
> - It relies on exception handling to handle control flow, which may be marginally slower.

> ```rb
> def create_or_find_by(attributes, &block)
>   transaction(requires_new: true) { create(attributes, &block) }
> rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique
>   find_by!(attributes)
> end
> ```

Using your example:

```rb
rating = user.recipe_ratings.create_or_find_by(
  recipe_id: recipe.id,
  delivery_id: delivery.id
)
```