# How to pipe Postgresql "psql" error to grep?

Tags: postgresql, grep, pipe, psql

I'm running a `psql` query like so:

```
$ psql --file=foo.sql "BAR-DB"
```

Where `foo.sql` contains the query. `foo.sql` has bad syntax, so the output is a list of error messages. My plan was to pipe the output to `grep` so I can filter specific error messages, but

```
$ psql --file=foo.sql "BAR-DB" | grep PATTERN
```

doesn't seem to do anything. `psql`'s documentation shows the optional flag:

```
-o, --output=FILENAME    send query results to file (or |pipe)
```

but I'm not sure how to use it to pipe the output to grep. What is the proper syntax?

Comment: How about `psql --file=foo.sql "BAR-DB" 2>&1 | grep -- PATTERN`?

Comment: Perhaps this post would help you: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28436918/6862601

Comment: @codeforester Your first suggestion got me what I wanted! Would you mind reposting it as an answer so I could mark it answered? (and could you explain what `2>&1` and `--` are doing?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could redirect the stderr of psql to stdout and then pipe it to grep:

```
psql --file=foo.sql "BAR-DB" 2>&1 | grep -- PATTERN
```