# INSERT with many subselects - performance and error selectivity

Tags: performance, postgresql, exception, constraints, plpgsql

I have a `plpgsql` function in which I want to add one row into a `Data` table
where many columns are updated from subselects from tables `TableA`, `TableB`
and `Session`:

```
CREATE TABLE TableA (
    a_id    SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    a_name  TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE TableB (
    b_id    SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    b_name  TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE Session (
    session_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
);
CREATE TABLE Data (
    session_id  INTEGER REFERENCES Session(session_id) NOT NULL,
    a_id        INTEGER REFERENCES TableA(a_id) NULL,
    b_id        INTEGER REFERENCES TableB(b_id) NULL
);
```

This is quite easy, but the function must be as fast as possible and also I
need specific error messages to discriminate between subselect fails.
Specifically:

- invalid (or `NULL`) `session id`
- invalid `a` name (if it was not `NULL`)
- invalid `b` name (if it was not `NULL`)

First I tried most straightforward approach - just selected all values I
needed, checked it for errors and then inserted the values:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION store_data(ssid INTEGER, a TEXT, b TEXT) RETURNS VOID
AS $$
DECLARE
    _a_id INTEGER = NULL;
    _b_id INTEGER = NULL;
BEGIN
    PERFORM 1 FROM Session WHERE session_id = ssid;
    IF NOT FOUND THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'INVALID SESSION: %', ssid;
    END IF;
    IF a_name IS NOT NULL THEN
        SELECT INTO _a_id a_id
            FROM TableA WHERE a_name = a;
        IF NOT FOUND THEN
            RAISE EXCEPTION 'INVALID A NAME: %', a;
        END IF;
    END IF;
    IF b_name IS NOT NULL THEN
        SELECT INTO _b_id b_id
            FROM TableA WHERE b_name = b;
        IF NOT FOUND THEN
            RAISE EXCEPTION 'INVALID B NAME: %', b;
        END IF;
    END IF;
    INSERT INTO Data (session_id, a_id, b_id) VALUES (ssid, _a_id, _b_id);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql SECURITY DEFINER;
```

This works just fine, but it's not very fast. I need to make it faster, so my
other approach was with subselects:

```
...
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Data (session_id, a_id, b_id)
        VALUES (
            (SELECT session_id FROM Session WHERE session_id = ssid),
            CASE WHEN a IS NULL THEN
                NULL
            ELSE
                (SELECT a_id FROM TableA WHERE a_name = a)
            END,
            CASE WHEN b IS NULL THEN
                NULL
            ELSE
                (SELECT b_id FROM TableB WHERE b_name = b)
            END
        );
    -- but no error handling :(
END;
...
```

This is a bit faster, but I can't figure out how to figure out which subselect
failed and what error to report.

**My question:** is there a way to make it faster while keeping specific error
messages?

The solution must work with postgres 8.4.

Comment: What's the expected (rough) ratio of success / fail for your function? Also, as *always*, add your version of Postgres, please.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I haven't measured it, but it should be something like 99% success, 1% fail. Version is 8.4 (in some instances it runs on 9.1, but it has to run on 8.4)

Comment: Version numbers are *always* important to questions here - even more so when using outdated software ([pg 8.4 has reached EOL 1 year ago](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)). My answer should work for 8.4 as well, but I did not test. There were two typos, now fixed.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter ok, I added the postgres version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming current Postgres 9.4.
Use the [**`RETURNING` clause of the `INSERT` statement**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-insert.html) to check after the `INSERT`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION store_data(ssid int, a text, b text)
  RETURNS void AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _rec record;
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO data (session_id, a_id, b_id)
   VALUES ((SELECT t.session_id FROM session t WHERE t.session_id = $1)
         , (SELECT t.a_id       FROM tablea  t WHERE t.a_name = $2)
         , (SELECT t.b_id       FROM tableb  t WHERE t.b_name = $3))   -- tableb!
   RETURNING *
   INTO _rec;

   IF _rec.session_id IS NULL THEN  -- cannot be NULL
      RAISE EXCEPTION 'INVALID SESSION: %', ssid;
   ELSIF _rec.a_id IS NULL AND a IS NOT NULL THEN  -- allow NULL input
      RAISE EXCEPTION 'INVALID A NAME: %', a;
   ELSIF _rec.b_id IS NULL AND b IS NOT NULL THEN
      RAISE EXCEPTION 'INVALID B NAME: %', b;
   END IF;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql SECURITY DEFINER
                        SET search_path = public, pg_temp; -- adapt
```

Each subselect results in a NULL value if the row in the look-up table cannot be found. Hence, exactly one row is always inserted (and returned).

Be wary of naming conflicts between parameters, variables and column names that have not been table-qualified.

You should probably provide a `search_path` when using `SECURITY DEFINER`. Details:

- [How does the search_path influence identifier resolution and the "current schema"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067335/how-does-the-search-path-influence-identifier-resolution-and-the-current-schema/9067777#9067777)

**If** you had [**`NOT NULL` constraints**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-constraints.html#AEN2541) on the columns `a_id` and `b_id` in table `data` as well, then all you would need is:

```
   INSERT INTO data (session_id, a_id, b_id)
   VALUES ((SELECT ssid FROM session t WHERE t.session_id = $1)
         , (SELECT t.a_id FROM tablea  t WHERE t.a_name = $2)
         , (SELECT t.b_id FROM tableb  t WHERE t.b_name = $3));
```

If one of the values results in being NULL, you get an error message telling you which `NOT NULL` constraint has been violated.

You may or may not want to insert missing values in the look-up tables:

- [Is SELECT or INSERT in a function prone to race conditions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15939902/is-select-or-insert-in-a-function-prone-to-race-conditions/15950324#15950324)

Comment: Thanks, but this won't work, because only `session_id` is `NOT NULL`. `a_id` and `b_id` can be `NULL`. I should've mentioned that, my bad. I'll edit the question (it was lost in anonymization). As for naming conflicts - that's why I use short non-conflicting parameter names instead of `$1` notation, while every column has unique longer name, so I don't have name all tables in selects and I can use  `JOIN <xx> USING (<PK/FK column>)` syntax. As for a search path, this was anonymized - in real code, I use fully qualified names like `namespaceX.funcY` for "my" db objects.

Comment: @JanSpurny: My first (main) version of the function does not assume `NOT NULL` constraints and should work *as is*. You could omit the check for `_rec.session_id` in the function as this is covered by a `NOT NULL` constraint, but it won't cost much to have it anyway. `SECURITY DEFINER`: Yes, this is good practice. I would still make it a habit to follow recommendations for [Writing `SECURITY DEFINER` Functions Safely](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createfunction.html#SQL-CREATEFUNCTION-SECURITY).

Comment: yes, it will work, but I'd have to add `AND a IS NOT NONE` to `IF _a_id IS NULL` to make sure I handle `NULL` in `a` and `b` parameters correctly. Thanks.

Comment: I added that to make it complete.