# auto_increment foreign key (postgresql )

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, entity-relationship

[image: Simple ER diagram]

company(companytype) is a FOREIGN KEY in this case.

c_type(ID) is a Primary key then it will be automaticlly incremented.
My question is : when the c_type(ID) will be incremented , will company(companytype) be automaticlly incremented too ?

When entering data, users are asked to select the company type, if it exists it will be used in the company table else a new one will have to be created.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you asking what will happen if an exisiting id in the c_type table is incremented? Just adding a new record to c_type should not effect the company table in anyway.

Comment: Ok thanks e4c5 eveny if I do MATCH FULL for the foreign key ?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I would like that the user fills a formular :
-companyname...
-companyfield...
and when it comes to the companytype , he has to add a type on his own, then I would like that the foreign key in this case compnay(companytype) takes automatically the c_type(ID) value, just to  save th information correctly.

Comment: You are still not being clear. If each company has it's own type why do you need two tables?

Comment: cos next time when another user fills the formular he can use the type in the existing table without typing it again

Comment: If you have concurrent access, consider: [Is SELECT or INSERT in a function prone to race conditions?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15950324/939860).

Comment: Thanks Erwin Brandstetter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no question of company(companytype) being auto incremented. What you need is an autoincrement (SERIAL) field for id in the c_type table. When the user specifies the company type, you need to insert into the c_type table and user the autogenerated id in the company table as the value for companytype field.

If you want subsequent edits in the c_type table to be reflected there, you would need to the  [ON UPDATE CASCADE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/ddl-constraints.html)

Comment: Thanks e4c5 I will try it, but in the Postgresql documentation I found this "CASCADE specifies that when a referenced row is deleted, row(s) referencing it should be automatically deleted as well. "
It's true only for deleting or for inserting too

Comment: Occupational hazard of using foreign keys! to avoid the deletion use ON DELETE NO ACTION (which is the default)

Comment: Thanks e4c5 I didn't try it yet but  I'll mark it as solved.
I'm a beginner, If you can give me a document to learn more about UPDATE CASCADE and DELETE RESTRICT and such options that'll be nice of you.
Thanks in advance

Comment: psotgresqltutorial.com is a good place for many topics on it here is the one for forign keys http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-foreign-key/

Answer (score 0):

In short **NO** ! Foreign Key are used for referencing to another table primary key !

Comment: That mean I have to add a new record in c_type first then copy ID on companytype ?

Comment: Yes, there need to be something for Foreign Key to refer to ! You cannot input companytype value that is not present in c_type.ID .
this might help.
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp