# ERROR: syntax error at or near "returning" on stored procedure - PostgreSQL 8.1.23

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, version

I am having a stored procedure as follows:

```
 INSERT INTO bakersfun.orderhead 

     (order_id,order_dt, customer_id, route_id, routenum, ordertype, create_station_id, create_stationtype, create_time,create_user_id,tran_time, tran_user_id,station_id)

   values 

     (nextval('bakersfun.orderhead_order_id_seq'),$1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, LOCALTIMESTAMP, $8, 

    default, default,$9) 

   returning  order_id;
```

While executing I am getting error as follows:

```
new.sql:15: ERROR: syntax error at or near "returning"
LINE 15: returning order_id;
```

**PostgreSQL version : PostgreSQL 8.1.23**

I noticed it works on **PostgreSQL 8.4.20**

What is the alternative so it could work on **PostgreSQL 8.1.23**.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15939902/is-select-or-insert-in-a-function-prone-to-race-conditions  and  http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/89643/return-the-id-after-insert-or-select   i hope these two link will help you to find answer

Comment: @Shubham Batra post it as an answer.

Comment: your problem is solve or not ?

Comment: @Shubham Batra not yet buddy.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE 
  l_id integer;   -- change data type according to you.
BEGIN

INSERT INTO bakersfun.orderhead 

     (order_id,order_dt, customer_id, route_id, routenum, ordertype, create_station_id, create_stationtype, create_time,create_user_id,tran_time, tran_user_id,station_id)

   values 

     (nextval('bakersfun.orderhead_order_id_seq'),$1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, LOCALTIMESTAMP, $8, 

    default, default,$9)     
  returning order_id into l_id; --< store the returned ID in local variable
   return l_id; --< return this variable
END
```

for more reference check these two link

[Is SELECT or INSERT in a function prone to race conditions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15939902/is-select-or-insert-in-a-function-prone-to-race-conditions)

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/89643/return-the-id-after-insert-or-select

Comment: getting error as `SQL error:

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "integer"
LINE 2:   l_id integer;  
               ^
`

Comment: `order_id` is of type Serial. You can see that I am inserting `order_id` as `nextval('bakersfun.orderhead_order_id_seq')`, So it is `order_id` not required to specify as IN or OUT parameter.

Comment: can you create sql fiddle

Comment: It is having only version 9.3. In 9.3 all things will work fine. So cant be created