# Get Id from a conditional INSERT

Tags: sql, postgresql, concurrency, upsert

For a table like this one:

```
CREATE TABLE Users(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT UNIQUE
);
```

What would be the correct one-query insert for the following operation:

Given a user `name`, insert a new record and return the new `id`. But if the `name` already exists, just return the `id`.

I am aware of the new syntax within PostgreSQL 9.5 for `ON CONFLICT(column) DO UPDATE/NOTHING`, but I can't figure out how, if at all, it can help, given that I need the `id` to be returned.

It seems that `RETURNING id` and `ON CONFLICT` do not belong together.

Comment: This logic really should be in the database?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter this seems more complicated than I thought. I was trying to figure out whether to go for a one-query solution within a Node.js application, or just to stick with `SELECT id FROM users WHERE name='text'`, check if found, and if not then do `INSERT...`, which is 2 queries, but now it seems way simpler than the one-query option. I didn't expect it to be this awkward. I was hoping the new `ON CONFLICT` would be of help, but alas, it ain't. Thanks for the links!

Comment: The matter is hugely complex as soon as concurrent write access comes into play. I'll add another answer.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter it would seem that the simplest solution is to use a transaction and do two separate queries - select+insert. That's what I'm using at the moment.

Comment: I think I found a better solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SELECT or INSERT a row in one command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6722344/select-or-insert-a-row-in-one-command)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The UPSERT implementation is hugely complex to be safe against concurrent write access. Take a look at [this Postgres Wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/UPSERT#RETURNING_behavior) that served as log during initial development. The Postgres hackers decided not to include "excluded" rows in the `RETURNING` clause for the first release in Postgres 9.5. They might build something in for the next release.

This is the crucial statement in the manual to explain your situation:

> The syntax of the `RETURNING` list is identical to that of the output
>   list of `SELECT`. **Only rows that were successfully inserted or updated
>   will be returned.** For example, if a row was locked but not updated
>   because an `ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE ... WHERE` clause condition was not
>   satisfied, the row will not be returned.

Bold emphasis mine.

For a ***single row*** to insert:

#### Without concurrent write load on the same table

```
WITH ins AS (
   INSERT INTO users(name)
   VALUES ('new_usr_name')         -- input value
   ON     CONFLICT(name) DO NOTHING
   RETURNING users.id
   )
SELECT id FROM ins
UNION  ALL
SELECT id FROM users          -- 2nd SELECT never executed if INSERT successful
WHERE  name = 'new_usr_name'  -- input value a 2nd time
LIMIT  1;
```

#### With possible concurrent write load on the table

Consider this instead (for ***single row*** `INSERT`):

- [Is SELECT or INSERT in a function prone to race conditions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15939902/is-select-or-insert-in-a-function-prone-to-race-conditions/15950324#15950324)

To insert a ***set of rows***:

- [How to use RETURNING with ON CONFLICT in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34708509/how-to-use-returning-with-on-conflict-in-postgresql/42217872#42217872)
- [How to include excluded rows in RETURNING from INSERT ... ON CONFLICT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35949877/how-do-i-insert-into-this-postgressql-with-on-conflict/35953488#35953488)

All three with very detailed explanation.

Comment: Do you see any problem in the earlier answer given by Clodoaldo Neto? What I like about it, it doesn't require PostgreSQL 9.5 to work.

Comment: @vitaly-t: It's a solid statement, but does not cover the mentioned race condition. It's also probably more expensive. You might add the `LIMIT 1` from my statement for performance.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My previous research was formulated here: https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/blob/master/examples/select-insert.md, and I hoped that I could improve it with a single-query alternative. But now given all the complexity of it, I'm not really sure if it can be considered an improvement. But at least it is good to know that it is possible.

Comment: @vitaly-t: You might add `FOR SHARE` or `FOR KEY SHARE` to the `EXISTS` subselect in Clodoaldo's answer to cover the race condition in older versions. Or compare to  `ON CONFLICT ... DO NOTHING` to compare apples to apples. Also, looking at your implementation on github, I would consider the [server-side function detailed in my linked answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15950324/939860) which is superior to multiple round trips to the db server in your approach.

Comment: I would post it as a comment but it would be too long so I reformed my answer.

Comment: @vitaly-t: Note the updates. A possible corner case wasn't covered.

Answer (score 3):

For a single row insert and no update:

```
with i as (
    insert into users (name)
    select 'the name'
    where not exists (
        select 1
        from users
        where name = 'the name'
    )
    returning id
)
select id
from users
where name = 'the name'

union all

select id from i
```

[The manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-WITH) about the primary and the `with` subqueries parts:

> The primary query and the WITH queries are all (**notionally**) executed at the same time

Although that sounds to me "same snapshot" I'm not sure since I don't know what *notionally* means in that context.

But [there is also](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING):

> The sub-statements in WITH are executed concurrently with each other and with the main query. Therefore, when using data-modifying statements in WITH, the order in which the specified updates actually happen is unpredictable. **All the statements are executed with the same snapshot**

If I understand correctly that *same snapshot* bit prevents a race condition. But again I'm not sure if by *all the statements* it refers only to the statements in the `with` subqueries excluding the main query. To avoid any doubt move the select in the previous query to a `with` subquery:

```
with s as (
    select id
    from users
    where name = 'the name'
), i as (
    insert into users (name)
    select 'the name'
    where not exists (select 1 from s)
    returning id
)
select id from s
union all
select id from i
```

Comment: The fact that CTEs are based on the same snapshot cannot prevent race conditions. One example: Imagine two transactions starting at virtually the same moment. Both find that 'the name' does not exist yet and try to `INSERT`. You get a unique violation. There are good reasons for the new `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT ...`

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I'm not sure what you describe is accurate when you use the word `transaction`, which implies the use of `begin` and `commit`. In such a case the second transaction would be locked till the first one has finished, by the very definition of transactions.

Comment: @Erwin: Now I get where your mindset is at. As I see it those two transactions are just that: transactions. One will fail with a proper unique violation message to be catch by and dealt with by the application. It is not like a misleading result was produced. I think that trying to avoid the second transaction from failing is over engineering. Not a significant gain compared to the added complexity.

Comment: @Clodoaldo: That's what UPSERT (or INSERT or SELECT) is about: to avoid the error and get the desired result in one step. And the case I mentioned is just one of several possible complications.

Comment: @vitaly-t: In Postgres, *every* DML statement runs inside a transaction. Most clients run in autocommit mode. `BEGIN` and `COMMIT` are optional to wrap multiple statements in one transaction. Transactions are not locked. Resources are locked - which can block transactions. Locks are acquired along the way and released at the end of a transaction. Concurrent transactions can run the same `SELECT` and find the same row "missing". Locks on missing rows are impossible in Postgres. More than one might try to `INSERT` the same key and only one would succeed with a unique index.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter thank you, I can see now that use of transactions in this case doesn't help at all, and so I corrected my example here: https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/blob/master/examples/select-insert.md