# Return rows from INSERT with ON CONFLICT without needing to update

Tags: sql, postgresql, upsert, postgresql-9.5

I have a situation where I very frequently need to get a row from a table with a unique constraint, and if none exists then create it and return. 
For example my table might be:

```
CREATE TABLE names(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT,
    CONSTRAINT names_name_key UNIQUE (name)
);
```

And it contains:

```
id | name
 1 | bob 
 2 | alice
```

Then I'd like to:

```
 INSERT INTO names(name) VALUES ('bob')
 ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING RETURNING id;
```

Or perhaps:

```
 INSERT INTO names(name) VALUES ('bob')
 ON CONFLICT (name) DO NOTHING RETURNING id
```

and have it return bob's id `1`. However, `RETURNING` only returns either inserted or updated rows. So, in the above example, it wouldn't return anything. In order to have it function as desired I would actually need to:

```
INSERT INTO names(name) VALUES ('bob') 
ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT names_name_key DO UPDATE
SET name = 'bob'
RETURNING id;
```

which seems kind of cumbersome. I guess my questions are:

1. What is the reasoning for not allowing the (my) desired behaviour?
2. Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It's the recurring problem of ***`SELECT or INSERT`***, related to (but different from) an UPSERT. The new UPSERT functionality in Postgres 9.5 is still instrumental.

```
WITH ins AS (
   INSERT INTO names(name)
   VALUES ('bob')
   ON     CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT names_name_key DO UPDATE
   SET    name = NULL
   WHERE  FALSE      -- never executed, but locks the row
   RETURNING id
   )
SELECT id FROM ins
UNION  ALL
SELECT id FROM names
WHERE  name = 'bob'  -- only executed if no INSERT
LIMIT  1;
```

This way you do not actually write a new row version without need.

<sup>I assume you are aware that in Postgres every `UPDATE` writes a new version of the row due to its [MVCC model](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/mvcc-intro.html) - even if `name` is set to the same value as before. This would make the operation more expensive, add to possible concurrency issues / lock contention in certain situations and bloat the table additionally.</sup>

**However**, there is still a **tiny corner case for a race condition**. Concurrent transactions may have added a conflicting row, which is not yet visible in the same statement. Then `INSERT` *and*  `SELECT` come up empty.

Proper solution for single-row UPSERT:

- [Is SELECT or INSERT in a function prone to race conditions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15939902/is-select-or-insert-in-a-function-prone-to-race-conditions/15950324#15950324)

General solutions for bulk UPSERT:

- [How to use RETURNING with ON CONFLICT in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34708509/how-to-use-returning-with-on-conflict-in-postgresql/42217872#42217872)

#### Without concurrent write load

If concurrent writes (from a different session) are not possible you don't need to lock the row and can simplify:

```
WITH ins AS (
   INSERT INTO names(name)
   VALUES ('bob')
   ON     CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT names_name_key DO NOTHING  -- no lock needed
   RETURNING id
   )
SELECT id FROM ins
UNION  ALL
SELECT id FROM names
WHERE  name = 'bob'  -- only executed if no INSERT
LIMIT  1;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I see this seems like a 'better' way to do it, but I'm not sure what the practical difference is with the method I described?

Comment: @ira: I added some more explanation above.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter -- does this always return an id? I tried and it didn't seem to work -- https://stackoverflow.com/q/46586793/435563 -- perhaps I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Ok ... so the bug with the above is this, I think: `SET    name = NULL where false` will not get a lock if `name` is already `null`.

Comment: Not the case, the confusion has been sorted out in https://stackoverflow.com/q/46586793/435563.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Does the "regular" upsert have any race conditions or problems other than PostgeSQL creating a new version of the row behind the scenes? ie: `INSERT INTO names(name) VALUES ('bob') ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT names_name_key DO UPDATE SET name = 'bob' RETURNING id;`