# INSERT ... RETURNING returns only after first insertion

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert

I've expected that the SQL-statement
`INSERT ... RETURNING *` would always return something but it seems to work only after the first insertion. The following insertions don't fail but also don't return anything. Is it the expected behavior of the statement?

I have a table `identities` that has a unique constraint on the columns `mrn` and `name`. I want to insert a record:

`INSERT INTO identities (mrn, name) VALUES('x', 'y') on conflict do nothing returning id;`

I get the `id` as expected
`1b3e43cc-722a-4703-91d3-6839287b6eff`

But the second insert doesn't return anything.

Comment: Yes, it's expected. `returning id` only returns a row if something go inserted. See e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40323799/return-rows-from-insert-with-on-conflict-without-needing-to-update)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Strange. It would be much better (and logical) if the statement helped me to identify the existing record...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SELECT or INSERT a row in one command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6722344/select-or-insert-a-row-in-one-command) also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42217872/1048572)

Comment: @Bergi Yes. But I've created a slightly different query based on the answer there. I `do update` on a column just to force `returning` to return the row. Thanks!