# Race conditions between INSERT ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING and SELECT

Tags: sql, postgresql, race-condition, upsert, transaction-isolation

Does a `SELECT` query following an `INSERT … ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING` statement always find a row, given the default transaction isolation (read committed)?

I want to `INSERT`-or-`SELECT` a row in one table, then reference that when inserting rows in a second table. Since [`RETURNING` doesn't work well with `ON CONFLICT`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34708509/1048572), I have so far used [a simple CTE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40323799/1048572) that should always give me the identity column value even if the row already exists:

```
$id = query(
  `WITH ins AS (
    INSERT INTO object (scope, name)
    VALUES ($1, $2)
    ON CONFLICT (scope, name) DO NOTHING
    RETURNING id
  )
  SELECT id FROM ins
  UNION  ALL
  SELECT id FROM object WHERE scope = $1 AND name = $2
  LIMIT 1;`,
  [$scope, $name]
)
query(
  `INSERT INTO object_member (object_id, key, value)
  SELECT $1, UNNEST($2::text[]), UNNEST($3::int[]);`
  [$id, $keys, $values]
)
```

However, I learned that [this CTE is not entirely safe under concurrent write load](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15950324/1048572), where it can happen that both the upsert and the select come up empty when a different transaction does insert the same row.

In the answers there (and also [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/212580/188406)) it is suggested to use another query to do the `SELECT`:

> start a new command (in the same transaction), which then can see these conflicting rows from the previous query.

If I understand correctly, it would mean to do

```
$id = query(
  `INSERT INTO object (scope, name)
  VALUES ($1, $2)
  ON CONFLICT (scope, name) DO NOTHING
  RETURNING id;`,
  [$scope, $name]
)
if not $id:
  $id = query(
    `SELECT id FROM object WHERE scope = $1 AND name = $2;`
    [$scope, $name]
  )
query(
  `INSERT INTO object_member (object_id, key, value)
  SELECT $1, UNNEST($2::text[]), UNNEST($3::int[]);`
  [$id, $keys, $values]
)
```

or even shortened to

```
query(
  `INSERT INTO object (scope, name)
  VALUES ($1, $2)
  ON CONFLICT (scope, name) DO NOTHING;`,
  [$scope, $name]
)
query(
  `INSERT INTO object_member (object_id, key, value)
  SELECT (SELECT id FROM object WHERE scope = $1 AND name = $2), UNNEST($3::text[]), UNNEST($3::int[]);`
  [$scope, $name, $keys, $values]
)
```

I believe this would be enough to prevent that particular race condition (dubbed "concurrency issue 1" in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42217872/1048572)) - but I'm not 100% certain not to have missed anything.

Also what about "concurrency issue 2"? If I understand correctly, this is about another transaction deleting or updating the existing row, inbetween the `INSERT` and `SELECT` statements - and it's more likely to happen when using multiple queries instead of the CTE approach. How exactly should I deal with that? I assume locking the `SELECT` with `FOR KEY SHARE` is necessary in the second code snippet - but would I also need that in the third snippet where the `id` is used within the same query? If it helps to simplify the answer, let's assume an `object` can only be inserted or deleted, but is never updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make absolutely sure that the single row in the first table is there, and it's ID returned, you could create a function like outlined here:

- [Is SELECT or INSERT in a function prone to race conditions?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15950324/939860)

To make sure the row also **stays** there for the duration of the transaction, just make sure it's locked. If you `INSERT` the row, it's locked anyway. If you `SELECT` an existing `id`, you have to lock it explicitly - just like you suggested. [`FOR KEY SHARE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html#LOCKING-ROWS) is strong enough for our purpose as long as there is a (non-partial, non-functional) `UNIQUE` index on `(scope, name)`, which is safe to assume given your `ON CONFLICT` clause.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_object_id(_scope text, _name text, OUT _object_id int)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
LOOP
   SELECT id FROM object
   WHERE  scope = $1
   AND    name  = $2
   -- lock to prevent deletion in the tiny time frame before the next INSERT
   FOR    KEY SHARE
   INTO   _object_id;

   EXIT WHEN FOUND;

   INSERT INTO object AS o (scope, name)
   VALUES ($1, $2)
   ON     CONFLICT (scope, name) DO NOTHING
   RETURNING o.id
   INTO   _object_id;

   EXIT WHEN FOUND;
END LOOP;
END
$func$;
```

You really only need to lock the row if it's conceivable that a concurrent transaction might `DELETE` it (you don't `UPDATE`) in the tiny time frame between the `SELECT` and the next `INSERT` statement.

Also, if you have a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint from `object_member.object_id` to `object.id` (which seems likely), referential integrity is guaranteed anyway. If you don't add the explicit lock, and the row is deleted in between, you get a foreign key violation, and the `INSERT` to `object_member` is cancelled, along with the whole transaction. Else, the other transaction with the `DELETE` has to wait until your transaction is done, and is then cancelled by the same FK constraint since depending rows are now there (unless it's defined to `CASCADE` ...) So by locking (or not) you can decide whether to prevent the `DELETE` or the `INSERT` in this scenario.

Then your call burns down to just:

```
query(
  `WITH o(id) AS (SELECT f_object_id($1, $2))
   INSERT INTO object_member (object_id, key, value)
   SELECT o.id, UNNEST($3::text[]), UNNEST($4::int[])
   FROM   o;`
  [$scope, $name, $keys, $values]
)
```

Since you obviously insert multiple rows into `object_member`, I moved `f_object_id($1, $2)` to a CTE to avoid repeated execution - which would *work*, but pointlessly expensive.

In Postgres 12 or later I would [make that explicit by adding `MATERIALIZED`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-WITH) (since the `INSERT` is hidden in a function):

```
WITH o(id) AS MATERIALIZED (SELECT f_object_id($1, $2)) ...
```

Aside: For the multiple `unnest()` in the `SELECT` list, make sure you are on Postgres 10 or later. See:

- [What is the expected behaviour for multiple set-returning functions in SELECT clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39863505/what-is-the-expected-behaviour-for-multiple-set-returning-functions-in-select-cl/39864815#39864815)

### Matters of detail

> Will it make any difference (apart from execution time) to do this in the application logic with multiple queries in the same transaction?

Basically no. The only difference is performance. Well, and short code and reliability. It's objectively more error prone to go back and forth between db and client for each loop. But unless you have extremely competitive transactions, you would hardly ever be looping anyway.

The other consideration is this: the matter is tricky, and most developers do not understand it. Encapsulated in a server-side function, it's less likely to be broken by the next application programmer (or yourself). You have to make sure that it's actually used, too. Either way, properly document the reasons you are doing it one way or another ...

> I really wonder whether my second snippet is safe, or why not (given the quote about visibility in the `SELECT` after the `INSERT`).

**Mostly** safe, but not absolutely. While the next separate `SELECT` will see (now committed) rows of a transactions competing with the previous UPSERT, there is nothing to keep a third transaction from deleting it again in the meantime. The row has not been locked, and you have no way to do that while it's not visible, and there is no generic predicate locking available in Postgres.

Consider this (T1, T2, T3 are concurrent transactions):

```
                               T2: BEGIN transaction
T1: BEGIN transaction
                               T2: INSERT object 666
T1: UPSERT object 666
    unique violation?
    -> wait for T2
                               T2: COMMIT
T1: unique violation -> NO ACTION
    finish statement
    can't return invisible object 666
                                             T3: DELETE object 666 & COMMIT
T1: SELECT object 666 -> no row!
    BOOM!
```

Typically it's extremely unlikely that it ever happens.
But it's possible. Hence the loop.

The other option is [`SERIALIZABLE` transaction isolation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/transaction-iso.html#XACT-SERIALIZABLE). Typically more expensive, and you need to prepare for serialization failures. Catch 22.

Comment: "*To make absolutely sure that the single row in the first table is there, and it's ID returned, you could create a function*" - yes, I've seen that question, and understand that a `LOOP` will be absolutely on the safe side. However, I'm not keen on writing an SQL function for this - will it make any difference (apart from execution time) to do this in the application logic with multiple queries in the same transaction? I can't call the function in a CTE for the insertion to the second table anyway, as I have to do extra application logic checks in between.

Comment: And what I really wonder is whether my second snippet is safe, or why not (given the quote about visibility in the `SELECT` *after* the `INSERT`). I understand that it might not be as fast ("*Try the `SELECT` first. This way you avoid the considerably more expensive exception handling*"), but does it work?

Comment: @Bergi: I added more details.

Comment: Thanks, the `DELETE` in a third transaction is what I forgot to consider!