# how can I translate a query to CTE?

Tags: postgresql, common-table-expression

I'm still having trouble understanding how CTE works.

I'm looking to make an insert. In case of conflict I use the on conflict do nothing but I want it to return the id to me (for the success of the insert or the conflict)

```
WITH inserted AS (
    INSERT INTO fiche(label) 
    VALUES ('label') 
    ON CONFLICT (label) DO NOTHING
    RETURNING *
)
SELECT * FROM inserted
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM inserted);
```

Comment: From docs [INSERT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html): *The syntax of the RETURNING list is identical to that of the output list of SELECT. Only rows that were successfully inserted or updated will be returned.*  So you will only get values returned if the `INSERT` succeeds not if it fails.

Comment: What is the `id` of the table? Is that an auto-generated value with a constraint (such as a primary key or `not null`)? Under what conditions will there be a conflict upon insert?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "*translate a query to CTE?*" - you already have a CTE!

Comment: As for your actual problem, see https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/129522/how-to-get-the-id-of-the-conflicting-row-in-upsert https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34708509/how-to-use-returning-with-on-conflict-in-postgresql https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40323799/return-rows-from-insert-with-on-conflict-without-needing-to-update

Answer (score 0):

Note that

```
SELECT * FROM some_relation
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM some_relation);
```

will always give you an empty result. Either `some_relation` is empty itself or if it is not empty `SELECT 1 FROM some_relation` is not empty and therefore `NOT EXISTS ...` always returns false and so no record is matching the `WHERE` clause.

What you want is to have the `VALUES` as a CTE. You can then reference the values from your `INSERT` statement and in a `SELECT` to compare those values to the result of the `RETURNING` clause.

```
WITH
vals AS (
    VALUES ('label')
),
inserted AS (
    INSERT INTO fiche(label) 
    SELECT * FROM vals
    ON CONFLICT (label) DO NOTHING
    RETURNING label, id
)
SELECT
    vals.column1,
    inserted.id
FROM vals
LEFT JOIN inserted ON vals.column1 = inserted.label
```

This should give you a row for each row in your `VALUES` clause and the second column will be `NULL` if it was not inserted due to a conflict or the inserted ID otherwise.

Comment: Except the OP is looking for the `id` of the existing row, not the value proposed for insertion.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Oh yes, that is right. I modified my answer accordingly, assuming the name `id` for the column.

Comment: Except the `DO NOTHING` means nothing will be returned in the conflict case. Therefore no `id`. See my comment to the question, also the docs [INSERT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html).