# Can't insert values using pl\pgSQL procedure

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert, plpgsql, upsert

I have a problem with my procedure. We have 2 tables : companies and typeofcompanies.  Companies have 3 columns ("companyid","companyname","typeofcompany") , typeofcompanies have 2 columns ("typeofcompanyId", "typeofcompany");

This is my code for insert values into companies:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_to_companies(c_name VARCHAR(255),toc INTEGER)
      RETURNS VOID AS $$
          DECLARE i integer;
           BEGIN
          FOR i IN SELECT "typeofcompanyId" FROM typeofcompanies LOOP
            IF toc = i THEN insert into public.companies(companyname, typeofcompany) VALUES (c_name,toc);
              END IF;
          END LOOP;
          IF(SELECT companyname FROM companies WHERE companyname = c_name) = NULL THEN insert into public.typeofcompanies(typeofcompany) VALUES (toc);
                                                                             INSERT into public.companies(companyname,typeofcompany) VALUES (c_name,toc);
          END IF;
          END;
    $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

So if we haven't typeofcompany we should create it. But when i SELECT insert_to_companies("1",5);  i take  ERROR: column "1" does not exist.   So i think it's very easier problem, but i spent more than 3 hour and can't find problem. Please, i need help....

code for creating table with liquibase

**companies:**

```
<databaseChangeLog xmlns = "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/1.9" xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/1.9
                      http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-1.9.xsd">
    <changeSet id="1" author="tiurinvalery@gmail.com" runOnChange="true" >
        <createTable tableName ="companies">
            <column autoIncrement = "true" name = "companyid" type ="BIGINT">
                <constraints primaryKey ="true"></constraints>
            </column>
            <column name="companyname" type="VARCHAR(255)">
            </column>
            <column name="typeofcompany" type="INTEGER">
            </column>
        </createTable>
    </changeSet>
 </databaseChangeLog>
```

**For type of companies:**

```
<databaseChangeLog xmlns = "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/1.9" xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/1.9
                      http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-1.9.xsd"  >
    <changeSet id="5" author="tiurinvalery@gmail.com" runOnChange="true" >
        <createTable tableName ="typeofcompanies">
            <column autoIncrement = "true" name = "typeofcompanyId" type ="BIGINT">
                <constraints nullable="false" primaryKey="true"></constraints>
            </column>
            <column name = "typeofcompany" type="VARCHAR(255)">
                <constraints nullable="false"></constraints>
            </column>
        </createTable>
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

Comment: Minimum requirement for this kind of question: Table definitions (`CREATE TABLE` statements showing data types and constraints) and your version of Postgres. Just listing your columns is not very useful.

Comment: Okey sorry, i should create my table with liquibase, so this is liquibase code:

Comment: Liquibase is irrelevant to the question. Please show SQL code. And I still can't see your version of Postgres. (`SELECT version()`) And clarify where `c_id+"_type"` is coming from and what it's supposed to do.

Comment: I haven't SQL code for create and insert tables. This code auto-generated by liquibase library.( I can show print-screen of database structure with column and data type if it can help). "PostgreSQL 9.5.9 on x86_64-pc-mingw64, compiled by gcc.exe (Rev5, Built by MSYS2 project) 4.9.2, 64-bit"    . And about c_id + "_type" - yes it's a logical mistake , but problem still after fix version(i edit code in the start question)

Comment: I could not understand your request.

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo. The next best thing to `CREATE TABLE` statements is the output of `\d companies? in psql (default interface). Please edit all basic information into the question.

Comment: I fixed the problem myself yesterday. Thank you for your help. The problem was due to inattention.

Comment: [So do you have your answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Yes, problem was with quotes. My code is right, but for insert i used " " quotes, right variant is ' ' .

Answer (score 0):

Table definitions could look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE company_type (
   company_type_id serial PRIMARY KEY
 , company_type    text UNIQUE NOT NULL
); 

CREATE TABLE company (
   company_id      serial PRIMARY KEY
 , company         text NOT NULL
 , company_type_id int REFERENCES company_type
);
```

I made a couple of changes:

- Not using double-quoted CaMeL-case names. Avoid that, if you can.

  - [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive/20880247#20880247)
- Using `integer` instead of `bigint` for PK IDs. I seriously doubt you'll exhaust the key space with company types in this century ...
- Using just `text`. `varchar(255)` typically is a misunderstanding in Postgres.

The best function (or just query) heavily depends on your use case. DB load, concurrency, exact requirements. If concurrent writes are possible, I suggest this to avoid race conditions:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_insert_to_companies(_c_name text, _toc text)
  RETURNS void AS
$func$
BEGIN
LOOP
   INSERT INTO company(company, company_type_id)
   SELECT _c_name, t.company_type_id
   FROM   company_type t
   WHERE  company_type = _toc;

   EXIT WHEN FOUND;

   -- if type is missing, insert and keep looping    
   INSERT INTO company_type (company_type)
   VALUES (_toc)
   ON     CONFLICT (company_type) DO NOTHING;
END LOOP;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=78a682b87f60f89161f8eea201515f75)*

Related (with detailed explanation):

- [Is SELECT or INSERT in a function prone to race conditions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15939902/is-select-or-insert-in-a-function-prone-to-race-conditions/15950324#15950324)