# Race Condition between SELECT and INSERT for multiple columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, concurrency, plpgsql, upsert

Note: This is a question which is a follow up of [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15939902/is-select-or-insert-in-a-function-prone-to-race-conditions/15950324?noredirect=1#comment98875244_15950324). You need to read the link to get context for this question. Also, this is for postgres v9.4

If we want to return multiple columns now instead of just 1 column, how can we achieve it?

Let's take a table t:

```
 create table t(tag_id int, tag text unique);
```

Now this is what I want:
whenever I call a method f_tag_id, I want it to return all the columns for the unique row if it exists in the table `t` else insert it and return all the columns.

So these are the things I tried for the `f_insert_tag`

Option1:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_insert_tag(tag_p_id int, _tag text)
RETURNS TABLE(_tag_p_id int, _tag_ text) 
AS
$func$
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO t(tag_id,tag) VALUES (tag_p_id, _tag);
        return query Select * from t where t.tag_id = tag_p_id;
        EXCEPTION WHEN UNIQUE_VIOLATION THEN  -- catch exception, NULL is returned
    END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Option 2:

```
   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_insert_tag(tag_p_id int, _tag text, out _tag_id int, out _tag_ text) 
AS
$func$
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO t(tag_id,tag) VALUES (tag_p_id, _tag);
        Select t.tag_id, t.tag from t where t.tag_id = tag_p_id into _tag_id, _tag_;
        EXCEPTION WHEN UNIQUE_VIOLATION THEN  -- catch exception, NULL is returned
    END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Option 3:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_insert_tag(tag_p_id int, _tag text)
returns setof t AS
$func$
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO t(tag_id,tag) VALUES (tag_p_id, _tag);
    return query Select * from t where t.tag_id = tag_p_id;
    EXCEPTION WHEN UNIQUE_VIOLATION THEN  -- catch exception, NULL is returned
  END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

All the 3 worked by themselves:

```
select f_insert_tag(1322, 'helloworldaa');
    f_insert_tag
---------------------
 (1322,helloworldaa)
```

For the other function, f_tag_id as well I tried many methods:

Option 1:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_tag_id(tag_p_id int, _tag text, out _tag_id int, out _tag_ text) 
AS
$func$
BEGIN
   LOOP
      SELECT t.tag_id, t.tag FROM t WHERE t.tag = _tag
      UNION ALL
      SELECT f_insert_tag(tag_p_id, _tag)
      into _tag_id, _tag_;

      EXIT WHEN _tag_id IS NOT NULL;  -- else keep looping
   END LOOP;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Option 2:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_tag_id(tag_p_id int, _tag text)
RETURNS table(_tag_id int, _tag_ text) AS
$func$

BEGIN
   LOOP
      SELECT t.tag_id, t.tag FROM t WHERE t.tag = _tag
      UNION  ALL
      SELECT f_insert_tag(tag_p_id, _tag)
      into _tag_id, _tag_;

      EXIT WHEN _tag_id IS NOT NULL;  -- else keep looping
   END LOOP;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

For both these, I got the same error:

```
select f_tag_id(22, 'test');
ERROR:  each UNION query must have the same number of columns
LINE 3:       SELECT f_insert_tag(tag_p_id, _tag)
                     ^
QUERY:  SELECT t.tag_id, t.tag FROM t WHERE t.tag = _tag
      UNION  ALL
      SELECT f_insert_tag(tag_p_id, _tag)
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function f_tag_id(integer,text) line 5 at SQL statement
```

Comment: As for Postgres 9.4: [Consider upgrading, this old version reaches EOL in Feb 2020.](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/) (Then you can simplify your function, too.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wrench in the works is <strike>`SELECT f_insert_tag(tag_p_id, _tag)`</strike> instead of

**`SELECT * FROM`** `f_insert_tag(tag_p_id, _tag)`

#### For Postgres 9.4

```
CREATE FUNCTION f_insert_tag(_tag_id int, _tag text, OUT _tag_id_ int, OUT _tag_ text) 
AS
$func$
 BEGIN
   INSERT INTO t(tag_id, tag)
   VALUES (_tag_id, _tag)
   RETURNING t.tag_id, t.tag
   INTO  _tag_id_, _tag_;

   EXCEPTION WHEN UNIQUE_VIOLATION THEN
      -- catch exception, return NULL
 END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;


CREATE FUNCTION f_tag_id(_tag_id int, _tag text, OUT _tag_id_ int, OUT _tag_ text) AS
$func$
BEGIN
LOOP
   SELECT t.tag_id, t.tag
   FROM   t
   WHERE  t.tag = _tag

   UNION ALL
   SELECT *                                              -- !!!
   FROM   f_insert_tag(_tag_id, _tag)
   LIMIT  1

   INTO _tag_id_, _tag_;

   EXIT WHEN _tag_id_ IS NOT NULL;  -- else keep looping
END LOOP;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=794f3d2bcc6d0eb0a379737521cdce4a)*

#### For Postgres 9.5 or later:

```
CREATE FUNCTION f_tag_id(_tag_id int, _tag text, OUT _tag_id_ int, OUT _tag_ text) AS
$func$
BEGIN
LOOP
   SELECT t.tag_id, t.tag
   FROM   t
   WHERE  t.tag = _tag
   INTO   _tag_id_, _tag_;

   EXIT WHEN FOUND;

   INSERT INTO t (tag_id, tag)
   VALUES (_tag_id, _tag)
   ON     CONFLICT (tag) DO NOTHING
   RETURNING t.tag_id, t.tag
   INTO   _tag_id_, _tag_;

   EXIT WHEN FOUND;
END LOOP;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=3fc60d093cb7c987ea67ada7106717cf)*

Basics here:

- [Is SELECT or INSERT in a function prone to race conditions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15939902/is-select-or-insert-in-a-function-prone-to-race-conditions/15950324#15950324)