# Own id for every unique name in the table?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, datatables

Is it possible to make a table that has like auto-incrementing id's for every unique name that I make in the table?

For example:

```
ID   NAME_ID    NAME  
----------------------
1       1       John
2       1       John
3       1       John
4       2       Mary
5       2       Mary
6       3       Sarah
7       4       Lucas
```

and so on.

Comment: What you show is *not* an *"auto-incrementing id for every unique name"*. It's the same id for the same name, and a classical normalization issue. Is database normalization a viable alternative for you? Either way, please start any such question with your Postgres version (`SELECT version ();`) and the current table definition (`CREATE TABLE` script).

Answer (score 1):

Use the window function [`rank()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html) to get a unique id per name. Or [`dense_rank()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html) to get the same without gaps:

```sql
SELECT id, dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY name) AS name_id, name
FROM   tbl;
```

I would advise *not* to write that redundant information to your table. You can generate that number on the fly. Or you shouldn't store `name` redundantly in that table, `name` would typically live in another table, with `name_id` as `PRIMARY KEY`.

Then you have a "names" table and run *"SELECT or INSERT"* there to get a unique `name_id` for every new entry in the main table. See:

- [Is SELECT or INSERT in a function prone to race conditions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15939902/is-select-or-insert-in-a-function-prone-to-race-conditions/15950324#15950324)

Answer (score -2):

First add the column to the table.

```
ALTER TABLE yourtable
ADD [UID] INT NULL;

``
ALTER TABLE yourtable
ADD constraint fk_yourtable_uid_id foreign key ([UID]) references yourtable([Serial]);
```

Then you can update the UID with the minimum Serial ID per Name.

```
UPDATE t
SET [UID] = q.[UID]
FROM yourtable t
JOIN
(
  SELECT Name, MIN([Serial]) AS [UID]
  FROM yourtable
  GROUP BY Name
) q ON q.Name = t.Name
WHERE (t.[UID] IS NULL OR t.[UID] != q.[UID]) -- Repeatability
```