# A call to a VOLATILE function breaks atomicity of a SELECT statement

Tags: postgresql, isolation-level, mvcc

Given (PostgreSQL 15.3):

```sql
create table test (
    test_id int2,
    test_val int4,
    primary key (test_id)
);
```

If these two transactions are run in parallel at `read committed` isolation level:

```sql
-- Transaction 1
insert into test (select 1, 1 from pg_sleep(2));
```

```sql
-- Transaction 2
select coalesce(
    (select test_val from test where test_id = 1),
    (select null::int4 from pg_sleep(5)),
    (select test_val from test where test_id = 1)
);
```

The second transaction returns `null` as it should because it is a single statement.

However, if the second transaction is replaced with:

```sql
create function select_testval
    (id int2) returns int4
    language sql strict volatile -- stable function will work as previous version
return (select test_val from test where test_id = id);

-- Transaction 2.1
select coalesce(
    (select test_val from test where test_id = 1),
    (select null::int4 from pg_sleep(5)),
    select_testval(1::int2)
);
```

It returns `1`, acting as a series of two statements each seeing a different snapshot of data.

---

So, my questions are:

1. Is it a proper behavior for a function call to introduce a separate statement looking at a newer snapshot? If it is, where is it documented?
2. Apparently, the `stable` function gets inlined in this case thus remaining a single statement. Is it possible for a `volatile` function call to get inlined as well under some circumstances thus changing concurrency semantics? If it is, how to control inlining?

---

Edit 1. Based on the feedback from comments edited the post to pinpoint the actual problem causing confusion. The original questions were rather trivial.

P. S. For context, I discovered this when was trying to find an idiomatic pure-SQL solution to concurrent inserts with unique constraint problem ([1](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/212580/concurrent-transactions-result-in-race-condition-with-unique-constraint-on-inser), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15939902/is-select-or-insert-in-a-function-prone-to-race-conditions)), without resorting to `plpgsql`.

Comment: How are you testing the parallel transactions? I am trying to reproduce it but I only get `null` only if the insert was not committed, which is expected.

Comment: Well, I usually use Node.js for repeatable testing. When executing transactions simultaneously in two side-by-side SQL console tabs in DBeaver, I add a `commit;` statement after `insert` and use bigger delays.

Comment: By the way, which PostgreSQL version are you using? Maybe the problem is version-specific. It was tested only with 15.3.

Comment: But it is all a single statement `SELECT COALESCE(...)` isn't it? You don't expect a single statement to see a changing view of the DB during that statement do you?

Comment: Each of your transactions are a single statement.  I believe there is no difference between repeatable read and read committed in such a case

Comment: Variant 2.1 does see the changes. So I am not convinced about a "single statement" argument unless there is a clear documentation on that.

Comment: @TarasSerduke Yes, [there is](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/271925/are-snapshots-generated-for-each-sub-query-inside-a-postgres-read-committed-tran) [clear documentation](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/128269/how-do-i-set-the-isolation-level-for-select-statement) on that, so I'm actually kinda surprised that using `VOLATILE` can circumvent the snapshot.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks, links you provided answer my questions from semantics standpoint at least.  Then the problem comes to what kind of constructs PostgreSQL views as a single statement...

Comment: @Bergi Specifying `volatile` is not strictly necessary as it is the default setting. I guess,  the case is that specifying `stable` makes the function body inlined thus getting back to a single statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, it seems that I really overlooked the standard documentation:

> `STABLE` and `IMMUTABLE` functions use a snapshot established as of the start of the calling query, whereas `VOLATILE` functions obtain a fresh snapshot at the start of each query they execute.

From [38.7. Function Volatility Categories](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/xfunc-volatility.html)

This behavior has nothing to do with inlining.

It is worth noting that the snapshot a `volatile` function obtains is in line with transaction isolation level. So when isolation is `repeatable read`, the function would not see any fresh data from other transactions.